# Duplicating VC's with similar code utilising Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am creating an application which utilizes core data. I am adding custom table view cells and saving their order. I have done this for one table view. However I have multiple table views and I dont know what to change in the code for it to work for the other table views. I have a data model with an entity called device. It has a string in it called 'name'. I need to know how to edit the code to make it compatible for the other table views
My code is as follows.
DeviceViewController.m:

```
@interface DeviceViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
@end

@implementation DeviceViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this    view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

// Fetch the devices from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name"]]];

return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete object from database
    [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Remove device from table view
    [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self. tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate




 #pragma mark - Segue

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateDevice"]) {
    NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    DeviceDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
}
}

@end
```

DeviceDetailViewController.m:

```
@interface DeviceDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DeviceDetailViewController
@synthesize device;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
if (self.device) {
    [self.nameTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];

}

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.device) {
    // Update existing device
    [self.device setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];


} else {
    // Create a new device
    NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];

}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear what is not working. You should tell us rather than just dumping the code and let us figure it out.

Comment: I need to have four more VC's like this but it is crashing when I build it. I need to be able to put the same code in all four instances. With the required changes. I need to know what changes to the code I need to make

Comment: Evidently you are not able to tell us what is not working. In this case it will be challenging to get an answer.

Comment: I have 5 different views. Each one has its table. I have managed to make on of them work properly. I now need to make the other four work independently. This is the code of one VC and it is working. I need to know how to implement this code in the other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Substitute the entity name with the entity name you need.
- Substitute the class type for this entity accordingly.
- Substitute the property names with the appropriate property names.
- Make sure the object property of the detail view controller is of the right type.
- Change the things above also in the detail view controller.

By the way, you do not need to repeat the code creating the managed object context all the time. You can get to the context via the object if you have one (as you do in the detail view):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = device.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what is the entity name?

Comment: It would be, say, "Owner" instead of "Device". Presumably you are displaying different kinds of managed objects in your other view controllers.

Comment: Do I have to have different strings in the entity? One for each VC?

Comment: I changed the entity to device1 and the string to name1. I changed the  NSMutableArray to devices1. I then implemented the changes in the device and devicedetail files. It still is not working , is there anything I forgot?

Comment: Don' just mechanically execute these steps. Think what you are doing. Your managed object model must of course contain those same entities. If you want to display the same kind of data, of course, use the old names. Make sure to delete your app from the device/simulator after you update the data model.